# Limiting State-space Controller

Tags: control-systems

I have a state-space representation of a system with a few inputs and outputs. Further, I've used LQRegulatorGains to (surprise, surprise) construct an LQ regulator controller. This is all well and good, but I now need to effectively clamp values that the controller can send as inputs to the system. This is meant to be a physical system, with inputs that should be able to range from 0 to some arbitrary constant, but no further. In some scenarios, the controller will send negative inputs to the system. Is there a way that I can send these inputs through some sort of clamping before StateResponse?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why not add a block between the controller and the system that does the clamping? This is what typically done.

Comment: Well, that's exactly what I want to do. I'm just unsure as to how I can do that...

Comment: To cascade two transfer functions, you multiply them, right? So you need to multiply the transfer function of your controller with the transfer function of the clamp block, this will be your new controller. You convert this to state space if you want, and then use StateResponse on it. So you just need to figure what the transfer function for your clamping block should be.  This forum https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/control-engineering  has questions on control systems, may be that will something you can ask there on how to make T.F. for clamp block.

Comment: Nevermind - the transfer function for a clipping (clamping?) block is not something I can find any information on, nor can I seem to derive it.